# Use Reflection in C# to get a constructor that accepts a type or a derived type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I'd like to use reflection on a certain type argument T to get its constructors.

The constructors i'd like to get are ones that accept certain Type ISomeType, or any type derived from it.

For example:

```
public interface ISomeType
{
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeType
{
}
```

I'd like to find constructors that either accept ISomeType, SomeClass, or any other ISomeType derived class.

Is there any easy way of achieving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public List<ConstructorInfo> GetConstructors(Type type, Type baseParameterType)
{
  List<ConstructorInfo> result = new List<ConstructorInfo>();

  foreach (ConstructorInfo ci in type.GetConstructors())
  {
    var parameters = ci.GetParameters();
    if (parameters.Length != 1)
      continue;

    ParameterInfo pi = parameters.First();

    if (!baseParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(pi.ParameterType))
      continue;

    result.Add(ci);
  }

  return result;
}
```

which is equivalent with

```
public IEnumerable<ConstructorInfo> GetConstructors(Type type, Type baseParameterType)
{
    return type.GetConstructors()
            .Where(ci => ci.GetParameters().Length == 1)
            .Where(ci => baseParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(ci.GetParameters().First().ParameterType)
}
```

when you add some LINQ magic

Comment: Instead of using a results holder in your first example you could use `yield return`.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: I was going for "as vanilla as possible" answer.

Comment: Thanks, this works. My bad was doing a GetType() for the ParameterInfo instance rather than ParameterType, duh!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Type myType = ...
var constrs = myType
    .GetConstructors()
    .Where(c => c.GetParameters().Count()==1
    && c.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISomeType))
    ).ToList();
if (constrs.Count == 0) {
     // No constructors taking a class implementing ISomeType
} else if (constrs.Count == 1) {
     // A single constructor taking a class implementing ISomeType
} else {
     // Multiple constructors - you may need to go through them to decide
     // which one you would prefer to use.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

base class doesn't know about own devived classes, that's why you can't get derived class's ctors. you must get all classes from assembly and find accept ctors among them